# Stochastic Sampling for Image Processing

Tags: python, image-processing

Can anyone help with the code for this? I want to reduce my image size by using stochastic sampling but cannot work out how to set the limits of my input patch.

```
# New smaller image
img_small = np.zeros((img.shape[0] // factor, img.shape[1] // factor),
                     dtype=np.int64)   

# Loop over the rows of the smaller image
for i in range(img_small.shape[0]):
    # Loop over the columns of the smaller image
    for j in range(img_small.shape[1]):
        # The input patch should consist of rows from factor * i to
        # factor * (i + 1) - 1, and columns from factor * j to
        # factor * (j + 1) - 1

        # input_patch = img[  # Extract the input patch

        # Can use np.random.choice(input_patch.flatten(), ...) to choose random
        # pixels from input_patch 

        # img_small[i, j] =  # Set the output pixel
            img_small[i, j] =
```

Answer (score 0):

The limits are given in the comments, simply apply them to the array. Using an example image
[image]

and using your code (added image load and converted it to greyscale - you will need to add colour handling if colour is required):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow

# load the image and convert to greyscale
image = Image.open('imglrg0.jpg').convert('LA')
# convert image to numpy array
img_lrg = np.asarray(image)
#imshow(img_lrg)

factor = 8

# New smaller image
img_small = np.zeros((img_lrg.shape[0] // factor, img_lrg.shape[1] // factor),
                     dtype=np.int64)   

# Loop over the rows of the smaller image
for i in range(img_small.shape[0]):
    # Loop over the columns of the smaller image
    for j in range(img_small.shape[1]):
        # The input patch should consist of rows from factor * i to
        # factor * (i + 1) - 1, and columns from factor * j to
        # factor * (j + 1) - 1

        # input_patch = img[  # Extract the input patch
        input_patch = img_lrg[i * factor:(i+1) * factor - 1, j * factor:(j+1) * factor - 1]

        # Can use np.random.choice(input_patch.flatten(), ...) to choose random
        # pixels from input_patch

        # img_small[i, j] =  # Set the output pixel
        img_small[i, j] = np.random.choice(input_patch.flatten())

imshow(np.asarray(img_small))
```

which results in (for `factor=8`. Not the best result, but recognizable. Maybe play with the sampling a bit to improve. I simply used matplotlib to quickly display the result so its off-color.):

[image]

Just as an addition on the sampling: choosing the average of three points like so `img_small[i, j] = np.average(np.random.choice(input_patch.flatten(), 3))` results in a substantial improvement:
[image]